# Converting curl with --form to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl request like this:

`curl -X POST http://mdom-n-plus-1.nonprod.appsight.us:8081/mesmerdom/v1/getByScreen -F "data={\"screen\":{\"screen-id\":\"57675\"}}"`

I am trying to convert it to python by using something like this:

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://mdom-n-plus-1.nonprod.appsight.us:8081/mesmerdom/v1/getByScreen"
payload = {"data": json.dumps({"screen":["screen-id", "57675"]})}
req = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print (req.text)
```

but I get the following error:

`io.finch.Error$NotPresent: Required param 'data' not present in the request.`

What would be the best way to convert the bash curl call to python request in this case?

Comment: `"data={\"screen\":{\"screen-id\":\"57675\"}}"` is escaped becasue of the shell. So you don't need to do `json.dumps`. Pass the `{"data":{"screen":{"screen-id":"57675"}}}` in the request.post in `json` param

Comment: I do this ```payload = {"data":{"screen":{"screen-id":"57675"}}}
req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))``` . Still I get the same error.

Comment: Even if I use the json parameter ```payload = {"data":{"screen":{"screen-id":"57675"}}} req = requests.post(url, json=payload)```, I get the same error.

Comment: `-F` in curl is form data. I think if you do json.dumps and send the content in `files` this will work. All you have to change `data=payload` from original code to `files=payload`

Comment: If i do this ```payload = {'data': json.dumps({"screen":["screen-id", "57675"]})}
req = requests.post(url, files=payload)
```, I get the same error `io.finch.Error$NotPresent: Required param 'data' not present in the request.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to `stackoverflow.com`.

`-F` switch of `curl` denotes `form-encoded` data.

passing `data` makes the `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded`
but it seems that server is accepting `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`
so we need to pass `files` as well. but since server is looking for actual data inside `form` we need to pass `data` as well.
So this should work:

```
import requests

url = "http://mdom-n-plus-1.nonprod.appsight.us:8081/mesmerdom/v1/getByScreen"

payload = { 'data' : '{"screen" : {"screen-id": "57675"}}'}

req = requests.post(url, files=dict(data='{"screen":{"screen-id":"57675"}}'), data=payload)
print (req.text)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Still geting the same error ```io.finch.Error$NotPresent: Required param 'data' not present in the request.```

Comment: can you run this `req = requests.options(url)` and show whats the output?

Comment: `<Response [404]>`

Comment: I have a curl request like this: curl -X POST ${HOST}/mesmerdom/v3/getByImageAndDom -F "data=$DATA" -F "dom=@$DOM" -F "image=@$IMG"  . How can I pass dom and image parameters in python ?