# Python - Error500 trying to POST form using requests (Content-Type: multypart/form-data)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I know this has been asked before here, but none of the solutions seem to work for me, so bare with me.

I can post the same request with Curl and it works just fine, if I translate it to Python with https://curl.trillworks.com/ the syntax is the same I was expecting but then I get http error 500 too.

**Example with Curl, which works fine**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" -F "center=40.416,-3.7" -F "propertyType=homes" -F "distance=2000" -F "operation=sale" "https://api.idealista.com/3.5/es/search"
```

**Example with Python, which returns error 500**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MyToken',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
}

files = {
    'center': (None, '40.416,-3.7'),
    'propertyType': (None, 'homes'),
    'distance': (None, '2000'),
    'operation': (None, 'sale'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api.idealista.com/3.5/es/search', headers=headers, files=files)

response.text
'{"message":"internal server error","httpStatus":500}'
```

Comment: Does this solves the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934261/converting-curl-with-form-to-python-requests/61937397#61937397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;' from the header made it work.

I don't understand why it is working using curl with  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;' , but it fails with Python. If anyone knows the reason, please let me know

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MyToken'   
}

files = {
    'center': (None, '40.416,-3.7'),
    'propertyType': (None, 'homes'),
    'distance': (None, '2000'),
    'operation': (None, 'sale'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api.idealista.com/3.5/es/search', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Now it works

```
response
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: I had the same problem. If you set just the Content-Type yourself what is missing is the boundary for the parts of the formdata. If you look at the Content-Type that requests generates it is 'multipart/form-data;boundary=<boundary>'.
With boundary being some byte sequence requests chose to seperate parts of the form data.